# How to add DirectXTK to UWP app for hololens?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, c++-cx, hololens, directxtk

I am trying to follow the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK) but I am unable to add a reference at the step when adding DirectXTK as a reference.

When I skipped this step and proceeded to use DirectXTK in my project it would not compile.

Any suggestions for getting DirectXTK setup on a UWP project for Hololens? If not this way a different way?

Comment: You probably want to check out this [fork](https://github.com/dngoins/DirectXTK) of the project

Comment: @arches123 created an issue for you https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/issues/115.

Comment: @aweez can you reply to the question on the GitHub issue. Thanks.